# What does the notation $R[x]$ mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Let $R$ be a ring and $S\supset R$ an extension. Let $x\in S$. I have the following statement which are equivalent
>
> - $x$ is integral over $R$
> - $R[x]$ is finitely generated as an $R$-module
> - There exists a faithful $R[x]$ module finitely generated as an $R$-module

Now my question is what does $R[x]$ mean? I mean we only had $R[X]$ and this is the polynomial ring over $R$ so the ring containing all polynomials in one variable $X$ with coefficients in $R$. But in $R[x]$ the $x$ is an element and not just a variable so I don't see what this means. Could maybe someone explain this?

Comment: It is the subring of $S$ generated by the subring $R$ and the element $x$, i.e. smallest subring containing these. Equivalently, it is the subring of all elements of $S$ of the form $p(x)$ for any $p \in R[X]$, hence the notation $R[x]$.

Comment: @lisyarus ah so for example if I take $R=\Bbb{Z}$ and then consider $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ then this is the ring of all elements of $p(\sqrt{5})$ where $p\in \Bbb{Z}[X]$?

Comment: It's a ring-adjunction - see the linked dupe (and its links).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$R[x] = \{ \ f(x)\ | \ f \in R[X] \ \}$, where $x \in S$ and $R[X]$ is the ring of polynomials with coefficients in $R$

just to clear the air, if $\alpha \in S$ then $R[\alpha]$ is exactly the evaluation of the polynomials $f \in R[X]$ at $\alpha$

Comment: thanks a lot so if I understood this correctly my example from above is correct

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).